Is the voting culture on SO different than other SE sites?
I've only recently really begun to answer questions on Stack Overflow after having only asked questions. I've spent a large portion of my time in Chemistry Stack Exchange where one typically easily garners votes (either + or -) in a short amount of time.
I'm not super strong in programming, but do learn when I see questions and try to come up with ways to answer. This is why I've started answering despite previously being shy of doing so.
However, my answers don't seem to receive any votes as they do on other parts of SE.
Do people here maybe think my answers are bad and maybe nobody wants to downvote, or is the voting culture here inherently different, or is it the sheer volume of questions on this site that might prevent my answers from being seen? I don't want to keep contributing if people think what I've written is a bunch of drivel.

One pattern I noticed is that you seem to be answering old questions, these would bring you reputation over time as long as your answer is good or brings in some useful information not in existing answers. What this also means though is that voting on these answers would take more time since they are sorted below the already existing answers (so there are lesser chances of people happening on your answer) in most of the sorting options.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Is it okay to answer old questions? I don't want to be annoying but usually, I come across those when I'm trying to figure something out in code and it doesn't work but I find an alternate route that DOES work and I make it an answer. I just want to make sure that's not taboo here.

@MelanieShebel it's okay (probably encouraged even) to answer old posts (with the usual caveat that the answer should bring something new to the table and not just repeat existing ones). My comment just points out that given the scale of SO answering old questions doesn't give you the "quick" rep it might give you on other sites, but as I mentioned before it will net you reputation over time.

Suggest you look at the sort of (especially generic) common critical & improvement comments that are left by people whose questions and/or answers and/or comments you consider good/helpful & apply their suggestions/principles/conventions to your posts.

"Is the voting culture on SO different than other SE sites?" - it even differs per tag. Stack Overflow has a pretty bad rep for being "toxic"; this is because curation is generally pretty strict with a higher chance for content receiving downvotes and close votes than might happen on other sites.

I just had a quick glance at your answers and saw that they are generally on older, very highly-viewed questions and the newest ones encompass Python, JS, R, Ruby and MySQL. That's often a quick heuristic for someone posting LLM answers. Clearly you are a real and apparently very knowledgeable person, but I wonder if this is partly another effect of people posting ChatGPT answers.

Agreed with @Gimby. Posts on SO can sometimes take months or even years to garner +10 score, but I've often seen it on the smaller sites posts receiving 10-100 score in a matter of days. My impression of the smaller sites is that they are much looser with quality control and more likely to upvote just about anything.

@philipxy some other stackexchanges are far more critical about question topic of questions and answer quality than SO in my experience. In effect, each community has their own needs, hang-ups and flavors of pedantry.

@philipxy In my experience the specific science field Stack sites don't generally suffer from quality problems like that. Sure there are some low quality questions, but the answers are generally high quality.

@MelanieShebel - I have a vaguely similar background. I joined SO many years ago, but posted not a single Q or A until a little over a week ago. I've made some goofs and been corrected a few times. You can mostly ignore rude posts from trolls with low reputations. It's harder when a high-rep user leaves a terse message. Just be aware that they're trying to help lots of people all over the site, so don't feel bad about a too-short message. But do make improvements to your answers as the comments come in. I've had downvotes retracted when I fixed problems.

@MelanieShebel FWIW: I've noticed that copy/paste of applicable paragraphs from man pages and/or language standards (available online) attract the most upvotes... It's a curious situation wherein helping an individual by finding bugs or fixing algorithms or suggesting alternative approaches is not really valued here, yet "RTFM" answers are... I suggest to NOT attach ANY significance to "rep points" and simply make worthwhile contributions when- & how- you can, and as you choose to. "All that glitters is not gold."

@Fe2O3 "finding bugs or fixing algorithms or suggesting alternative approaches is not really valued here" Fixing bugs and fixing algorithms are usually extremely narrow in scope and helps exactly one person, so yes, we shouldn't value them. "yet RTFM answers are" there are very few literal copy-and-paste answers, especially newer ones, that are highly upvoted. There is most often valuable accompanying explanation which well-deserves the upvotes.

@PasserBy I'm not going to debate what one can deduce when one has been looking at what transpires on SO. Hard to estimate how many times one sees tiny variations on the same difficulty asked and then answered with the same block of text copied from a spec. Even duplicates (and near duplicates) are to be valued?? Every asker's problem is important to them and many Q's represent tiny variations of the same problem. It's inappropriate to clam "narrow in scope". [...]

@PasserBy [...] This Q&A is covered in less than 2 pages of any textbook. 32K pts for the asker, and 44K pts for the accepted answer... and that's just one of the hundreds of Q&A that are based on this operation that is clearly explained in any textbook and/or YouTube video. The repository is bloated and does not operate according to any comprehensible scheme. Thus, my advice to the OP to "make worthwhile contributions" and don't worry about "Up/Down vote" tallies.

@MelanieShebel the simple answer, as explained in the Ryan answer, is just that there is no "community that reads all the questions" in SO, it is far too large.  However it is a fact that, to be absolutely blunt, there is nothing that good programmers hate more than bad or newb programmers.  (And this goes up and down the chain. Leading domain expert programmers, despise expert programmers. Expert programmers despise good programmers.  Good programmers despise mediocre programmers .. and so on.)  It's an internet commonplace that SO is the site where 100% of users are snotty, seething.

.. It's utterly pointless trying to be politically correct about it .. there is nothing that good programmers hate more than bad or newb programmers. And (as with all social media), there is no fear of physical retribution on anonymous QA sites, so every writer has the guts to be as rude as they want!  It's just the nature of programming, and of SO. \

Also, don't forget that ("no, seriously") there are people who care about "points on an internet page" and in general the SE sites are the home of, the source of, that sort of bizarre otaku culture. (I use otaku in the negative sense here.) And within the SE world, SO is the ultimate, non plus ultra, example of that culture!

@Fattie given that there's no objective assessment of what constitutes a "good programmer" I would suggest your conjecture would be better phrased as "there's nothing that people who believe that they are good programmers hate more than people they believe are beneath them". Truly good programmers enjoy teaching other people and don't try to belittle them.

@IanNewson lol couldn't agree more.  (But sure, someone who works with, you know, the internals of compilers or gpu programming is a more  programmer than someone who putters around with scripting web pages or unity3d, you know.)

@IanNewson in fact I feel a sort of fatherly pride when I see the young'uns get it. We are on the verge of algorithm-driven software completely ruining the next generation of programmers, they will need all the help they can get to reach any level of "good". We all need to double down on sharing wisdom.


However, my answers don't seem to receive any votes as they do on other parts of SE.
Do people here maybe think my answers are bad and maybe nobody wants to downvote, or is the voting culture here inherently different, or is it the sheer volume of questions on this site that might prevent my answers from being seen?

The short answer is "there are a lot more posts relative to the number of people browsing the site looking for content, so upvotes mostly come in when someone with the same problem finds your post via a search and it helps them, rather than people seeing your post when it's new."  On a lot of sites, it's practical for the site's regulars to read every single new post submitted to the site.  On Stack Overflow, that would be a full-time job (probably several full-time jobs)—we average roughly 2000 questions per day, and a pretty similar number of answers.
That voting over time shouldn't be underestimated.  For example, you didn't post any answers between early 2021 and last month, but you were steadily earning upvotes on your existing answers that whole time.

I also have the impression, that the most common errors messages, which people may expire, gain by far the most upvotes. These are often the most primitive problems, while sophisticated Q/A often go merely unnoticed. The less specialized, the more upvotes. These upvotes indicate popularity, not exactly quality.

@MartinZeitler on "These upvotes indicate popularity, not exactly quality." - that sounds a bit like it's a bad thing. I like to think of it more as "these upvotes indicate the number of folks you helped". So it still stands that more primitive problems will get more upvotes, but it feels more justified, because people are just more likely to hit those than more nuanced problems, so more upvotes means you will have unblocked more people / saved more people-hours that would have been spent inefficiently.

In addition, the breadth of computer programming is far greater than the breadth of a single scientific field (say, Chemistry for example). There's a lot you might not know about in Chemistry, but generally you can probably tell when an answer is solid in theory or sound in logic. In programming, different languages can work completely differently, so there's no guarantee that people who see your content will be at all familiar with that language or its peculiarities. Even the number you start counting from could be different!

I think this is just as true with smaller sites as well - I probably get more reputation per post on Meta.SE with posts of broad interest to that community, than I do on super user. Admittedly I'm not really at the point where I'm too bothered by either, and I'm aware a lot of the issues I have these days are painfully niche.

@Zoltán Just see my answers and their votes, I so often get down-votes on technically correct answers, assumedly from people who failed to apply the provided solution - and immense number of upvotes, whenever I can find some new error message, for which I can provide a line of code, which causes the error message to disappear. I usually upvote, whenever an answer actually taught me something.

@TylerH Re "the breadth of computer programming is far greater than the breadth of a single scientific field (say, Chemistry for example)", I think the exact opposite is true. If someone is a competent developer, but knows nothing about (say) Rust, they could apply themselves and become a SME in a fairly short period of time. I don't think that  argument would hold for (say) chemistry or physics or biochemistry.

When you answer niche questions, especially old ones, almost nobody will bother to upvote. People only seem to upvote in extraordinary cases, if they agree with everything about the question and the answer. On the other hand you can easily gain a downvote (or even a vote to close) because someone disliked one detail of the answer or didn't like the question.

@skomisa Physics and Chemistry are different fields, so that's not really an apt comparison. Biochem would, but that's no different than someone using R for statistics or data science instead of traditional programming--there's overlap on multiple sites. ANd if you talk about someone applying themselves and learning, that's just syllogistically throwing the premise out the window. If someone takes the time to learn a new subject, related or not, of course they will then know about that subject. How long it takes them to learn something is irrelevant.

@Zoltán you may like to believe* that, but only because you're not thinking. The people you're thinking of aren't registered. They don't care about rep or voting culture. They aren't here to stroke their fragile ego. Voting is a concern of validation seeking hobbyists. They don't share these motivations. What you believe seems unlikely.

Yes. This can be explained by multiple things, one of which -at least for me- important, is about the global amount of votes.
For me, the first generation of users vote more than others as they know the importance of voting. It's also necessary to make the website work (otherwise no one can have gain the privilege to comment, which can be difficult ...).
On Stack Overflow, the first generation of users helped the site grow, but they are now partially leaving the website. Now a new generation is coming which is not fully trained to the Q&A system.
We can see this with the amount of votes per month cast on questions less than 31 days after the question was created (SEDE query):

Also because the amount of new users is getting lower (SEDE query) (here the picture shows the total number of users):

To conclude, we are witnessing more inactive users, or existing users not participating because they do not really care anymore.

This analyses is fundamentally incomplete because the main factor is votes/time/post. You'd have to normalize per post, and for a broader picture it'd be necessary to consider views/post and correlate that with members/(total number of posts) to account for RyanM's hypothesis that repository size dilutes attention/post and thus votes/post

@bad_coder Yes it could be completed with more analysis. But, as now there is all previous posts that are already valuable and can still get votes. So, we have more users, more posts but less votes. We know the amount of vote/post will decrease. And this need lot of research, but that's the job of SO staff ;)

I also don't agree with the negativeness that users are leaving and the first generation was the best and voted a lot more. Because that doesn't account for the thousands of off-topic posts that got lots of upvotes and were completely useless, opinion-based, trivial, duplicate, etc... The main fact is that posting has gotten harder as repositories mature and the Q&A programming marketplace has more competition than when SO started and enjoyed a near monopoly.

For this point, you're not wrong. It's more difficult now to keep your post opened than at the beginning, almost everything were allowed (we can see it with bad posts from 2011 closed few month ago...). Also, I didn't explain it in the answer, but the "users are leaving" is also about the direction of SO and multiple issue with Staff/decision etc that can lead users that were investing time into SO to leave the community and continue as simple user without really take the time to interact

One thing worth emphasizing is that the first graph only shows votes on questions (rather than votes on all kinds of posts).

"We can see this with the amount of votes per month" is a very misleading summary for that particular query. That query shows "the number of votes questions got within the month they were posted". So it's not "amount of votes per month" which would be much more considering votes which are older than months as well as votes on answers.

What on earth happened in... looks like early 2015?

@KarlKnechtel What Happened to Stack Overflow in 2014?. Abdul, see https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1853304#graph

Making a split between old gen and new gen is relevant, but I'd also say there is a middle gen. In my eyes, and meta more and more frequently proves this, the actual old gen think of the site as it was when they signed up; pretty much the wild west with few rules. They operate in a bubble and just answer whatever they please as they've always done. Old gen is starting to realize now what middle gen already knows; they are painfully aware of how Stack Overflow grew and its many rule changes and tries to adhere to them strictly to this day. While the new gen just want this site to be Reddit.

@Gimby I couldn't resist my urge to write a comment to appreciate this. Very well put!

I'm probably part of the new generation, that votes very rarely. But

The attention span. Not just instagram and other social media with scrolling habbit, there is a lot of work in work, the higher the effectivity, the higher the workload expected from you, which especially as young dev puts you in difficult position to get the grasp on the things. You don't know from which technologies to choose, you feel lost in the amount of frameworks, ... while in job you just develop inhouse stuff for which you won't find help here or neither can ask questions due to the fact, that nobody knows it.

It's easier to answer political, theoretical, hypothetical, or other just 'want-opinion-like' questions stuff, where you don't have to think that much. If it's close to the pub-talk it will get more answers.


I will try to give upvotes from now on.

somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386212/997587

@Minko_Minkov You have some reasonable critiques here.  However, regarding "I've also written questions myself, and just had toxic commentors respond.", I looked to see if there was maybe a user in need of moderation.  Here's every comment ever posted to your questions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  Could you please clarify which of these are the ones where just toxic commenters responded?

@RyanM My apologies for my previous message; it was over-exaggerated. I was using examples I had seen in the past to convey my criticisms of the site, and I may have pushed it a bit. It can be difficult to convey tone in writing, and I assure you I'm not overly upset.
I realize that using the word "toxic" might be a bit harsh. What I meant was that a couple of individuals in the screenshots seemed more focused on getting the question taken down rather than being helpful.
I may have a different threshold or perspective on what constitutes (very minorly) toxic behavior.

I wanted to share some constructive criticism about the site. Despite this, I still find the site valuable and continue to use it. But I can be overbearing in my negative criticisms.

@Minko_Minkov: If someone thinks a question should be closed, it's fairly normal for them to comment about why, with the intended audience being other potential close-voters, not just the person who posted the question. (Or to encourage OP to delete before more downvotes.) Some people will actively avoid helping in comments on questions they don't think should have been posted, because that encourages more low-quality questions by giving the poster what they wanted.  I haven't looked at your questions and don't know how much if any of that applies to comments under your posts.

@Fe2O3 Flagging is the correct approach.  It hasn't been handled yet because there are hundreds of flagged comments and no one has gotten to that one yet.  With current moderator levels and the dramatic increase in moderator workload due to AI-generated content, you should expect to need to wait more than 3 hours in the general case, especially depending on when you flag something.  Please be patient and we will handle such flags eventually.

@Minko_Minkov "and is by all means, not beginner friendly at all." Yes, it's not meant to be. It's a site for professionals and hobbyists, not for people starting out and not for learning. It's for solving and answering programming issues and questions via Q&A, and even more importantly, helping future visitors with that. "At the end of the day, with how good AI is at answering questions, why should I bother with toxic SO anymore?" if it really works for you, then sure. I would still not call it "good" at answering questions. 1/2

@Minko_Minkov 'Programming is more than just "How do I write this code?." It's also, "How do you deploy this on a server?"' Yes, and we have dedicated StackExchange sites for those things. We have devops, superuser, software engineering, webmasters, and a lot more for things that are other than the purpose of StackOverflow. StackOverflow, however, is for the sole purpose of having high-quality Q&A about programming (writing code) that helps out the questioner, but more importantly, helps out future visitors. It should act like a library of Q&A just for code, pretty much. 2/3

@Minko_Minkov 'and then a mod will come in and take down the question because "Question is not direct enough." Well in my opinion, because I understood what they were asking, it actually was direct enough.' Are you sure that they would appear as "direct enough" to future visitors as they do to you? Once again, the objective is to help future vistors with a similar problem, not the OP alone. The OP's question, and your answers, are both stepping stones to achieve that goal. If a question and its answer(s) only help the OP alone, then I would argue they are not very useful at all. 3/3

@SyedM.Sannan "then I would argue they are not very useful at all." This is a self-fulfilling assessment. Maximally, when three readers "don't like" a certain question that question to be closed and eventually purged. Over the last 16 years, how many times has the same question been asked and then purged, only to be asked again weeks or months later? I witnessed, on at least two occasions, reasonable questions purged within hours of being posted. (I checked. The repository holds no retrievable copy of the subject being asked.) Unacknowledged bias is inherent in the system.

@Fe2O3 If you think a post was deleted incorrectly, then ping one of the mods or members who have enough reputation to vote to undelete inside a chatroom and have them assess the problem. I don't disagree with the fact that there can be biases and mistakes, all curators on this site are humans (At least, I wish to think so.). But the point is that there are processes made to care to those mistakes and reverse things. If you genuinely think a post shouldn't have been deleted, then by all means, have it reviewed again. 1/2.

@Fe2O3 However, if they come to the same conclusion multiple times, maybe ask them, or yourself, if there might have actually been a problem with that post. I am sure you would know at that point anyways. 2/2.

@SyedM.Sannan Been down that road... One Q was badly phrased, but comprehensible and salvageable. (One hi-rep user posted a good answer!) I attempted to "lightly" improve the text of the question, but adamant moderator argued, "You cannot read the OP's mind." No?? I and several others had NO difficulty understanding a fixable question, but moderator would brook no resistance... Poof! Q&A gone off into oblivion... Even in THIS very thread, I see one of my comments has been purged because someone didn't like having their lack of appreciation pointed out... The system is broken...

@SyedM.Sannan The user posting this question ("low hanging fruit") has acquired >30K rep pts since 2008 as a result. Does this mean that they are "knowledgeable" in 2024? This EASILY could have been their one-and-only "newbie" question posted 16 years ago, and they return to the site 16 years later with astonishing "powers" that more recent inductees have no hope of achieving... The system is broken...

@Fe2O3 There are exceptional cases, but the point is that the system is generally working but has its problems. You cannot claim that the system is "broken" while benefiting from it at the same time. StackExchange is the only user-curated platform that is this spam-free and the mods are doing a great job fighting against AIGC even though they don't have a lot of manpower. The system has its flaws that can be fixed and addressed, but it's a huuuugee strech to claim that it is broken. It's like people advocatnig for gettig rid of the education system and starting anew because of its flaws. 1/2.

@Fe2O3 We can address and fix them in both cases. No need to consider them fundamentally broken, because they are not. The problems you mentioned are the common problems of any user-curated platform virtually or physically. Perhaps we can be a little more optimistic and work towards making this very platform better and fixing its problems instead of thinking of something fundamentally different, because that too, will have its flaws, and likely greater ones. 2/2.

@SyedM.Sannan You're entitled, of course, to carry on with your optimistic approach. "GenAI" was not an issue until about ~2 years ago, but virtually nothing had been achieved in the many preceding years of "discussion" of revealed issues. There's been an acknowledged gulf between the site's "ideals" and its "realities" (leading to this OP posting this question.) Every "case" is "exceptional" for those involved. It's those myriad "exceptions" that make SO the private, privileged fiefdom of its early adopters. [1/2]

@SyedM.Sannan "...likely greater ones." => "fear of the unknown." Topical post over here. And, with its -14 votes, here's some further reading. THAT is the reaction to proposing incremental improvements(?) to the site...

@Fe2O3 My friend, it's not fear of the unknown. It's simply that a working system does not need to be scraped but has its flaws addressed. In fact, creating new systems is generally an extreme excercise that should only be done when existing systems are entirely ineffective. If SO wasn't working, it would be failing in achieving its main objective, and that is to have a library of high-quality Q&A that helps out people who visit it with the same problem. Despite its flaws (That for the thousandth time, must be addressed), it's working quite well.

@Fe2O3 "And, with its -14 votes, here's some further reading. THAT is the reaction to proposing incremental improvements(?) to the site..." Please don't take downvotes at heart. On Meta, they are simply a measurement of agreement vs disagreement. They only truly matter on the main site in terms of post quality. I did actually view that post before you sent it. Viewed all your meta posts :) and I do understand that you raise some very valid points but once again, they aren't that significant to consider a system broken. W.r.t. post, I think starball's answer is sufficient, and where they say-

I just don't think it's super realistic to turn this level of wording into a rule.

@SyedM.Sannan I don't take any of it to heart any more. I'm here for my own amusement; nothing more. Filling an excess of free time and missing observing (and shaking my head over) the "strutting" and "ego wars" after working in the industry for many years. No greater pleasure than finding the flaws, bugs and deficiencies posted by SME answers after seeing those UV'd a few times (mindless cheers given for "reputation", when the "answer" is off-target or even dead wrong.) My advice to this OP: "attach [NO] significance to [votes]... make worthwhile contributions when you can," Cheers!

@SyedM.Sannan "It's a site for professionals and hobbyists, not for people starting out and not for learning." I refer you to that Q&A I linked that has the asker with >30K rep from this single (2008) question... If that is NOT a novice-level question, then I don't know what is... The system is, and has been, broken for a long, long time.

@Fe2O3 1. Novice-level questions are welcomed as long as they aren't duplicates, off-topic, or have some other problem for that matter. 2. Hobbyists and professionals can still ask novice-level questions in topics they are new to. But a complete beginner/newbie to programming as a whole usually does not even know how to formulate a question properly. A lot of the times, they are unaware of what exactly they are even asking and how to phrase it. And that is the reason due to which I said it's not a beginner-friendly platform, beginners don't (usually) even know how to ask.

@Fe2O3 I myself have been in that boat before. In fact, I was question banned at one point of time but got out of it. It was primarily because of cases in which I had a problem but had no idea which direction to go and hadn't tried anything prior. I was simply asking people to do free work for me, which is not what StackOverflow is about. StackOverflow is about solving problems. You should normally have at least some level of idea of what you are dealing with before asking on StackOverflow, specially knowing what your actual problem is and what you have currently tried to fix it.

@Fe2O3 Lastly, to conclude this conversation, things from 2008 are usually poor example of how the site works. The rules, circumstances, and even the state of the internet overall was much different back then. The site has evolved heavily from that point of time, in some ways better, and in some ways, arguably worse.

@SyedM.Sannan "The site has evolved heavily [since 2008]..." However, one glaring problem has been ill-conceived, manifest for years, debated to death, yet left unaddressed... I agree. Time to let this go. Wishing you a pleasant day... Cheers!...
